# Bitbucket pipelines yml needs to run a command in AWS App container after deployment to EBS

Tags: spring-boot, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ebs

I am using a bitbucket-pipelines.yml to deploy my Spring boot app to AWS beanstalk. After it is deployed to the AWS ec2 instance, I want to run simple command to extract the jar file (that is because of a requirement to access some files later and it is not related to this question)
Can I include a command in the yml file to run this command inside the ec2 instance after the app deployment?

My yml code is something like this:

```
        - step:
          caches:
            - maven
          name: deploy admin
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.6.7
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET'
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'xxxxxx'
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'xxxxx'
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'xxxxxxxx'
                ZIP_FILE: 'xxxxxx/target/xxxx-$version.jar'
                S3_BUCKET: '$S3_BUCKET'
                VERSION_LABEL: 'xxxxx-module-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}'
                COMMAND: 'all'
          after-script:
            - admin/target/classes/env_ready.sh
```

I know this after-script will run, but not inside the ec2 instance. Is there a way that I can run a command inside the ec2 instance that the application is running? (which was deployed by the AWS beanstalk) and the app deployed directory is the /var/app/current/

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First, not so elegant, will be running the after script through the SSH connection. Syntax is simple: `ssh user@host some_command`, but it requires duplicating the SSH connection by the each line of your after-script. There is also a different syntax, which requires one connection:

```
ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH'
#commands to run on remote host
ENDSSH
```

In the YAML file it will look like this:

```
after-script:
 - |
   ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH'
   #commands to run on remote host
   ENDSSH
```

This solution has some downsides:

- you need to find the IP/hostname of EC2 instance in the pipeline
- you need to propagate user password/SSH key

Option two is to use Codedeploy. This is AWS native service, that allows you to deploy some solutions into various targets, including Elastic Beanstalk applications. The appspec file will also let you configure the scripts triggered as hooks in different phases of deployment. There is also after deploy hook, dedicated for the purpose you need.
From the Bitbucket pipeline YAML file, deployment script will be very simple: triggering the CodeDeploy, then verify (wait) until it completes. unfortunately, changing it into CodeDeploy way will require much changes on your side.

Choose the option that suits you better :-)